# PhantomJS not mimicking browser behavior when looking at YouTube videos

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I posted this question to the PhantomJS mailing list a week ago, but have gotten no response.  Hoping for better luck here...

I've been trying to use PhantomJS to scrape information from YouTube, but haven't been able to get it working.

Consider a YouTube video embedded into a web page via an iframe element.  If you load the URL referenced by the src attribute directly into a browser, you get a full-page version of the video, where the video is encapsulated in an embed element.  The embed element is not present in the initial page content; rather, some script tags on the page cause some Javascript to be evaluated which eventually adds the embed element to the DOM.  I want to be able to access this embed element when it appears, but it never appears when I load the page in PhantomJS.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();

page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; rv:24.0) Gecko/20130909 Firefox/24.0";

page.open("https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ", function (status) {
  if (status !== "success") {
    console.log("Failed to load page");
    phantom.exit();
  } else {
    setTimeout(function () {
      var size = page.evaluate(function () {
        return document.getElementsByTagName("EMBED").length;
      });
      console.log(size);
      phantom.exit();
    }, 15000);
  }
});
```

I only ever see "0" printed to the console, no matter how long I set the timeout.  If I look for "DIV" elements I get "3", and if I look for "SCRIPT" elements I get "5", so the code seems to be sound.  I just never find any "EMBED" tags, even though if I load the URL above in my browser I do find one soon after page-load.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried just dumping the full HTML to the console? It may be that YouTube is responding with something different than what you see in your browser, perhaps based on user-agent filtering.

Comment: That's why I set the User-Agent in my code above, to the same string that my actual browser uses.

Comment: Hmmm. So you do. Sorry; posted that comment from a mobile device. Nonetheless: have you dumped out the full HTML to see what you're getting?

Comment: I can't recall if I tried this during my experiments a week ago.  But if I'm sending the same user-agent as my browser's, is there any reason to expect different HTML?  I've written programs that do a fair bit of automated web access, and I can't think offhand of any sites that I couldn't make behave just be setting the user agent appropriately.

Comment: Well, I agree that the user agent is probably not it. But, since the `<embed>` tag isn't being found by your script, the question is why not. The full HTML may answer that.

Comment: Habe you considered that YouTube js detects that the phantomjs browser is incapable of rendering the video and therefore doesn't even bother?

Comment: Sure, that's a reasonable possibility.  But of course I'd prefer a definite answer to a hypothesis.  If Youtube didn't obfuscate its Javascript I might have been able to determine if that's what's happening already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Patrick's answer got me on the right track, but the full story is as follows.

Youtube's Javascript probes the browser's capabilities before deciding whether to create some kind of video element.  After trawling through the minified code, I was eventually able to fool Youtube into thinking PhantomJS supported HTML5 video by wrapping `document.createElement` in the page's `onInitialized` callback.

```
page.onInitialized = function () {
  page.evaluate(function () {
    var create = document.createElement;
    document.createElement = function (tag) {
      var elem = create.call(document, tag);
      if (tag === "video") {
        elem.canPlayType = function () { return "probably" };
      }
      return elem;
    };
  });
};
```

However, this was a misstep; to get the <embed> tag I was originally after, I needed to make Youtube's code think PhantomJS supports Flash, not HTML5 video.  That's also doable:

```
page.onInitialized = function () {
  page.evaluate(function () {
    window.navigator = {
      plugins: { "Shockwave Flash": { description: "Shockwave Flash 11.2 e202" } },
      mimeTypes: { "application/x-shockwave-flash": { enabledPlugin: true } }
    };
  });
};
```

So that's how it's done.

Comment: Hi @Sean, I'm trying to capture a screenshot of Youtube using PhantomJS, but I just can't. I don't see any errors - the page is being loaded but the video window is black. I've tried putting your snippet of code everywhere in my script but it comes out black each time.  Can you give a full example of how to use it?  Many thanks ;)

Comment: @elad I don't think it's possible.  All my code does is trick Youtube into thinking phantomjs supports video playback so that it will insert a <video> or <embed> element onto the page, but phantomjs will just ignore that element, since it really doesn't support video at all.

Comment: does this work when i want to take screenshots of the website? as i am getting "Video playback isnt supported on this device"

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! Only way I found to get a dynamically loaded video src was using your code

Answer (score 5):

phantomjs does [not support flash](http://phantomjs.org/supported-web-standards.html), or the [html5 video element](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10839).

Comment: I'm not expecting it to support either of those things.  What I do expect is that Youtube's Javascript should add an <embed> tag to the DOM like it does in my browser, which will not have any further effect in PhamtomJS, but which I can then read the attributes of.

Comment: yes - but it does not inject an embed before the video starts playing. check the source in any other inspector.

Comment: You've lost me.  I don't expect a video to play at all, just for an embed tag to be added.  Why isn't it?

Comment: because it does not add the embed until you click to start the video.

Comment: That's not what I see.  For example, after I visit the URL in the code above, I can get my browser to inspect the DOM and tell me how many embed elements it finds, and I get 1.  I have not at that point interacted with the page in any way, and certainly not by starting the video playing.

Answer (score 0):

As on option - try to build *phantomjs* with video/audio support by yourself.

Original answer link: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10839#issuecomment-331457673