# Mimicking HTML5 Video support on PhantomJS used through Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to extract the source link of an HTML5 video found in the video tag . Using Firefox webdrive , I am able to get the desired result ie -

```
[<video class="video-stream html5-main-video" src='myvideoURL..'</video>]
```

but if I use PhantomJS -

```
 <video class="video-stream html5-main-video" style="width: 854px; height: 480px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: none;" tabindex="-1"></video>
```

I suspect this is because of PhantomJS' lack of HTML5 Video support . Is there anyway I can trick the webpage into thinking that HTML5 Video is supported so that it generates the URL ? Or can I do something else ?

tried this

```
try:

    WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//video")))


finally:


    k = browser.page_source


    browser.quit()


soup = BeautifulSoup(k,'html.parser')


print (soup.find_all('video'))
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to test?

Comment: @Rafael,  The link I tried was actually a YouTube video. I used Firefox 33 which seems to produce source URL upon inspecting element.

Answer (score 2):

The way Firefox and phantomjs webdrivers communicate with Selenium are quite different.

When using Firefox, it signals back that the page has finished loading after it loaded some of the javascript

Differently in phantomjs, it signals Selenium that the page has finished loading as soon as it is able to get the page source meaning it wouldn't have loaded any javascript.

What you need to do is [Wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) for the element to be present before extracting it, in this case it would be:

```
video = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//video")))
```

EDIT:

Youtube first checks if the browser supports the video content before deciding whether to provide the source, theres a workaround though described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146353/phantomjs-not-mimicking-browser-behavior-when-looking-at-youtube-videos)

Comment: I'm sorry , but what do I do with this video object ? . I tried (edit in question) but still got the same result

Comment: The video object is the element selected, you don't need to parse it in BeautifulSoup. But it should work the way you have, if you remove the `try` clause does it return an error of element not located?

Comment: No , it does not return an error , but instead -[<video class="video-stream html5-main-video" style="width: 854px; height: 480px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: none;" tabindex="-1"></video>]

Ie - exactly what I got before

Comment: But if it works on Phantomjs you're good to go, wasn't that what you wanted? EDIT: Oh it doesn't generate the URL, yeah that's probably because PhantomJS doesn't have a graphical support

Comment: Is there anything I can do ? Perhaps another headless browser that does support HTML5 or Flash ?

Comment: Is that java ? Can I implement it on through Selenium in python ?

Comment: Yes, the principle is the same